# Angular 1.5 Selected Attribute on First Option

Tags: javascript, angularjs, automated-tests

I recently updated to Angular 1.5, but found that it breaks a very corner case testing feature -- we test a page to see if a certain option is selected in an ng-options:

```
<select name="User" ng-model="userModel" ng-options="user.key as user.name for user in users">
        </select>
```

This produces html like this:

```
<option value="string:user1" >User1</option>
<option value="string:user2" >User2</option>
```

If the first option in the list is selected, then there won't be a "selected" attribute. Otherwise it will be there on the option that is selected, like this:

```
<option value="string:user1" >User1</option>
<option value="string:user2" selected="selected">User2</option>
```

Is there any way for the "selected" attribute to appear on the first option of the list if it's selected? As far as I can tell, this worked like that back in Angular 1.2 and before, but was changed in 1.2.19. (https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/8366)

Is there some workaround, or another attribute I can set?